# Create array node dynamically from string

Tags: php, arrays

I want create array node dynamically from string. In below example, I have  create node from string that I want to append in array.

```
$addkeyArray=array('overlay','help','type');
$arrayNode='';
$appMainData=array();
foreach ($addkeyArray as $childkey => $childvalue) {
 $arrayNode.="[".$childvalue."]"; 
 } 
echo  $arrayNode;
```

Output is:

> [overlay][help][type];

I want to reassign some value to `$appMainData[overlay][help][type]`.

Answer (score 1):

`$arrayNode.="[".$childvalue."]";` that's string operation, you are appending values in a string. In order to add a value to an array you need to do this:

change

```
$arrayNode.="[".$childvalue."]";
```

to

```
$arrayNode[]=$childvalue;
```

PS: `echo` on array won't work, you may use `var_dump` or `print_r`

Comment: You are right But I want  to reassign value to this array  $appMainData['overlay']['help']['type'] .Above will create another array.

Comment: i see that's interesting, kindly update your question too

Comment: ys I want to create hierarchy dynamically from another string. In simple word I have array $appMainData multidimensional array I want user can pass node in json to change node value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your after?

```
<?php
$addkeyArray = array( 'overlay', 'help', 'type' );
$arrayNode   = '';
$appMainData = array();
foreach ($addkeyArray as $childkey => $childvalue)
{
 $arrayNode[ $childvalue ] = ''; 
 } 
var_dump( $arrayNode );
```